# Smallest circles enclosing points with minimized cost

Tags: python, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, cluster-analysis, minimize

I am trying to find the smallest circles enclosing points using a hierarchical search (in a tree). I searched a lot and I seem to only find smallest enclosing circle (singular) algorithms online. This is for a university class so I am asking for possible solutions and ideas more than actual code.

My problem is that I have a formula that involves two constants and the radius of a circle to compute its cost and I need to minimise the total cost. This means that for a set of points (x,y), I could find one circle enclosing all points, or multiples circles, each enclosing a part of the points, depending on the cost of each circle.

As an example, if the formulae is 1+2*radius**2, my answer will surely have multiple small circles. All points must be in a circle at the end.

My goal is to use a graph search algorithm like a*, branch and bound or breadth first and build a tree using a state and its possible actions.

I am currently trying to write my possible actions as adding a circle, removing a circle and change a circle's radius. To limit compute time, I decided to only try those actions on positions that are between two points or between two sets of points (where the center of my circles could be). But this algorithm seems to be far from optimal. If you have any ideas, it would really help me.

Thanks anyway for your help.

If the question is unclear, please tell me.

Comment: How many points are there?

Comment: The number of points is a variable. It could be only one, maybe hundreds of points, or even thousands.

Comment: If a circle encloses one point with radius zero then the optimal solution is a circle at each point.  Is there a a minimum radius or a minimum number of points per circle?

Comment: Because of the cost formulae, which is using constants (like C + K*Radius**2), the best solution can be different than this. As an example, if C = 1000, then one big circle would be better than multiple small circles.

Comment: Ahh - obvious - thanks.  So K-means with a modified cost function can perform gradient descent on the problem - but no guarantee of the global optimum

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to focus on finding optimal solutions. You have a lot more options if you're open to approximate solutions, and I'm sure there will be other answers.

I would approach this problem by formulating it as an integer program. Abstractly, the program looks like

```
variable x_C: 1 if circle C is chosen; 0 if circle C is not chosen

minimize sum_C cost(C) * x_C
subject to
for all points p, sum_{C containing p} x_C >= 1
for all circles C, x_C in {0, 1}.
```

Now, there are of course infinitely many circles, but assuming that one circle that contains strictly more area than another costs more, there are O(n^3) circles that can reasonably be chosen, where n is the number of points. These are the degenerate circles covering exactly one point; the circles with two points forming a diameter; and the circles that pass through three points. You'll write code to expand the abstract integer program into a concrete one in a format accepted by an integer program solver (e.g., GLPK) and then run the solver.

The size of the integer program is O(n^4), which is prohibitively expensive for your larger instances. To get the cost down, you'll want to do column generation. This is where you'll need to figure out your solver's programmatic interface. You'll be looking for an option that, when solving the linear relaxation of the integer program, calls your code back with the current price of each point and expects an optional circle whose cost is less than the sum of the prices of the points that it encloses.

The naive algorithm to generate columns is still O(n^4), but if you switch to a sweep algorithm, the cost will be O(n^3 log n). Given a pair of points, imagine all of the circles passing by those points. All of the circle centers lie on the perpendicular bisector. For each other point, there is an interval of centers for which the circle encloses this point. Compute all of these event points, sort them, and then process the events in order, updating the current total price of the enclosed points as you go. (Since the circles are closed, process arrivals before departures.)

If you want to push this even further, look into branch and price. The high-level branching variables would be the decision to cover two points with the same circle or not.